# Extracting Y-coordinates for list1, for X-coordinates of list2 while their lengths are not same

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, data

I have two lists

```
list1={{1,2},{3,4},{5,6},{7,8},{9,10},{11,12}};
list2={{1.3,12},{3.2,14},{5.4,15},{7.1,16},{9.5,17},{11.6,18},{12.7,19.7}};
```

X coordinates from both lists represent the same parameter and they are slightly off, while the Y coordinates are from different parameters. The lengths of lists are not the same.
I would like to have Y coordinate values in list1 for X coordinates of list2.
Now list1 has to look like `{{1.3,Y of list1 = ?},{3.2,?},{5.4,?},{7.1,?},{9.5,?},{11.6,?},{12.7,?}}`;
It would be highly appreciated if someone helps with this for even larger data sets.
Thanks very much for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct an interpolating function from `list1` and evaluate it at x values of `list2`:

```
iF = Interpolation[list1, 
      "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Automatic, "WarningMessage" -> False}];

interpolatedlst1 = {#, iF@#} & /@ list2[[All, 1]]
```

> ```
> {{1.3, 2.3}, {3.2, 4.2}, {5.4, 6.4}, {7.1, 8.1}, {9.5, 10.5}, 
>  {11.6, 12.6}, {12.7, 13.7}}
> ```

Alternatively, use [`TimeSeriesResample`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeriesResample.html) with first column of  `list2` as the second argument:

```
interpolatedlst1b = Quiet@TimeSeriesResample[list1, {list2[[All, 1]]}, 
   ResamplingMethod -> {"Interpolation", InterpolationOrder -> 1}]
```

> ```
> {{1.3, 2.3}, {3.2, 4.2}, {5.4, 6.4}, {7.1, 8.1}, {9.5, 10.5}, 
>  {11.6, 12.6}, {12.7, 13.7}}
> ```

```
ListPlot[{list1, list2, interpolated2},
   Mesh -> All,
   Epilog -> {ColorData[97]@3, Dashed, Line @ interpolatedlst1}, 
   PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: @ kglr: Thanks very much. Your code is very useful